# Undefined Symbols error in Xcode with Unity build using Firebase

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine

Firebase 10.20.0

Unity 2022.3.20f1

Xcode 15.2

MacOS 14.3.1

iOS 16.4.1

I am attempting to build a simple Unity project onto my phone. The build includes Firebase Firestore. It runs fine in Unity, and builds to Xcode fine, however when I attempt to build from Xcode onto my iPhone I run into problems. The build gets to the end and then stops with these errors:

ld: Undefined symbols:
_Firebase_Firestore_CSharp_USE_FIRESTORE_FUTURE_VOID_get, referenced from:
_FirestoreCppPINVOKE_USE_FIRESTORE_FUTURE_VOID_get_m7B1C87EAC194B1820A555C55DD80D14E09D43D04 in libGameAssembly.a4
_FirestoreCpp__cctor_m01F392D9C6AE94A071E8F744E8129BB34E246734 in libGameAssembly.a4
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[Picture of main error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVCif.png)

[Picture of the little error summary. I don't understand why it says SDK iOS 17.2 when my phone is on iOS 16.4.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xop05.png)

[Full Xcode windoe just in case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WE3ee.jpg)

Things I have tried based on various suggestions around the internet:

- Adding and removing Firebase Authentication dependencies
- Adding "-Id64" to the "Other Linker Flags" in the Build Settings for UnityFramework
- Downgrading Firebase to 9.6.0
- running "pod deintegrate && pod cache clean --all" then "pod install"
- Deleting the /Pods folder and running "pod install"
- Deleting DerivedData in Xcode

Nothing. At some point I did something which added something related to 'Arm64' to the error, but it was all still pretty much the same and I haven't been able to replicate it.

Every time I try to build an app to iPhone from Xcode I run into errors but I'm currently feeling hopeless and all advice is appreciated.

Comment: please provide the [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and error in text form.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this myself after much headache. I believe the issue was related to the way I was uploading my project to GitHub and not fully putting everything Firebase related into the .gitignore, then when I pulled the repository onto a separate machine I am building on, it was trying to use old Firebase assets from the original machine.

**To solve, I created a fresh Unity project on the machine I was building on, added all non-Firebase assets from my original project (just copied and pasted), then imported Firebase into the new project entirely fresh, and I got it to build in Xcode without errors.**

In the original project, it seems I had forgotten to add the Plugins folder (in Unity) to .gitignore, which still contained old Firebase assets (two folders named iOS and tvOS). When they were transferred to the Mac I was building on, it caused the errors.

If you've done it right, when you go to import Firebase to Unity, all Firebase assets will be **new**, meaning **all** assets in the package manager window will be checked when adding.

Hope this helps anyone else who may come across this.